# PostMessage: Guaranteed to be delivered?

Tags: c++, windows

In my C++ app, I have a background thread that does some work, putting the results into a heap-allocated block of memory, and calling [PostMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to deliver the results to the Main-Thread.

Typically, when the Window receives the message, it processes the results, then does a `delete` on the memory specified by the `lParam`.

But I'm concerned that the window may exit before it gets around to processing the message and deleting the memory.

Does `PostMessage` somehow guarantee that the target window will get a chance to process the message?
If not, is there any well-known technique for knowing if the Window freed the memory, or if the background thread needs to be responsible for deleting it?

Comment: Thread race might get the window destroyed before late posted message delivery, in which cases there is nowhere to dispatch the message. Instead of posting "strong reference" to parameter, I instead put them on internal queue, which is either flushed on window destruction, or otherwise deleted from in posted message handler.

Comment: Note that messages can be posted from outside your application, so their content should be considered untrusted input.  What can you do with a pointer from an untrusted source?

Answer (score 3):

`PostMessage` will definitely be put in the message queue of the receiving window.  There is no guarantee that the window will be there, however.  It could have been destroyed by that time.
One way to help assure the message will get there is to create your own, hidden window (COM often uses this technique) and post to its queue.  That way you have control over when the hidden window is destroyed.  We employed this method for many years in real-time data delivery.

Having the background thread delete the memory is a bad idea and can lead to a race condition where it does not know when it is OK to delete.  Better to post to your own window and delete it there when you are done with it.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the classic message loop of a UI thread:

```
   MSG msg;
   while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
   {
     TranslateMessage(&msg);
     DispatchMessage(&msg);
   }
```

Your message posted from the other thread will be fetched and dispatched, but its delivery depends on whether the target window has been successfully created (and not yet destroyed). You could consider handling the message directly in the message loop, if you have control over it. Yet, things can get complicated when there is another (nested) message loop, which can be created as a result of handling some Windows messages. A simple example of this is a modal dialog, but some more complex things like COM call-outs can also incur nested message loops.

Thus, you should not rely upon guaranteed message delivery. Consider using a global data structure like queue or list (protected from simultaneous access with a critical section) to queue your data objects. Then you can still post a message using `PostMessage` and pass a pointer to your data object in `lParam`, but in your message handler you'd need to locate the object in the global queue and process (or discard) the objects which were queued earlier, but for some reason haven't got processed. Generally, when your thread exits (`WM_QUIT` message arrived in the loop above), you should do some processing on whatever was left in the queue, too.

Comment: Great recommendation of how to actually *solve* the problem.  As a side benefit it protects against shatter attacks, because you can detect pointers that don't actually correspond to queue items.  Well, your data processing might still get confused, but you won't dereference wild pointers.  Also, SList is suitable for such a queue, and avoids the need for a critical section.